# Arch: Apache change DocumentRoot on /home - 403 Access forbidden

Tags: apache, permissions, archlinux

Tried looking at the wiki and googling. No success.

I changed the documentRoot directory to /home/user/web/ in httpd.conf

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "/home/user/web/"
<Directory "/home/user/web/">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
# viewed by Web clients. 
#
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>
```

Then as per wiki, I ran `chmod o+x /home/user/web/` and even `chmod o+x /home/user/`

I have my index.html in there /home/user/web/index.html with one h1 element. Still after `systemctl restart httpd` I still get

```
[Thu Aug 30 16:52:40.918808 2018] [core:error] [pid 1537] (13)Permission denied: [client ::1:37306] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/user/web') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

Which makes me to think its permission issue, but don't know how to proceed from here?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following points for working your apache site.

1. Selinux
2. user and ownership it should be the same which is in httpd.conf file
3. set 755 permission
4. If there is any .htaccess file please rename and access if it is working then you need to look .htaccess file.